# App Crash On CoreFoundation CFRelease

Tags: ios, crash

App crashed at `brk` instruction of `CoreFundation CFRelease`. I am trying what causes this issue. Did some research, and the only thing I know right now is that might be a memory issue. But the stack and console didn't provide more detail message.

Below is the crash stack.

[image: Crash]

This is my first time, having an issue and completely no clue on where the issue is. Wish that I can get some hint from the experienced engineers here on **what I can use and how I can find the issue**.

My app is composed with a c++ library (written by our research team), a core framework, (written by me, includes a static .a library, wrapping the c++ library using objective c, objective c++, and with public apis, and models in swift), a map framework (written by me in swift and including carto mobile sdk - a map framework, and it requires the core framework)

Thanks so much for your time and help.

Comment: did you activate exceptions breakpoint?

Comment: @thorb65 its not activated before it crashed and I haven't found a way to easily reproduce it yet. I activate the breakpoint after that but have not yet hit the crash.

Comment: We are facing a similar issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Jelly Sorry no. And it is crashing randomly without any pattern. I experience the crash in a rate of once 1-2 months. So really have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: @Jelly Have you found a solution? Seems it is crashing more and exception breakpoint doesn't break. I have no idea where the problem is.

Comment: @nuynait, unfortunately no. Its not that frequent for us so we left it aside for now. I would be really interested if you find the issue.